# Laravel sessions not working after inserting record to database

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I a having a strange problem in laravel. I am using sweet alerts and laracasts flash package which work with sessions. they are working else where but when I insert a database entry using model I do not get any flash message in blade view. I am using model events when I don't use model events they work fine.
Can any body guide how can I resolve this. I do want to use model events too
in following snippet alert()->success in not working right after Message::create([]);

```
try
        {
            Message::create([
                'customer_id'   => $customer->id,
                'sid'           => time().bcrypt(time()),
                'corr_id'       => time().bcrypt(time()),
                'sender'        => $request['subject'],
                'receiver'      => $customer->contact,
                'body'          => $request['body'],
                'place_holder'  => 'inbox'
            ]);
            alert()->success('Exception as Inbound Created For '.$customer->full_name,'Success')->autoclose(1500);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        catch (QueryException $e)
        {
            alert()->error($e->errorInfo[2],'Sorry')->autoclose(2000);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code? What's the error? Have you ever read how to ask a question?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the code snippet

Comment: You have to debug it step by step. First, put a die() before return to see if you have any warning or notice. If not, check if you have any javascript wrror in your next page